# Issue with setting value to 'true' in event listener

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of Javascript that includes an event listener for a keypress event. When the `f` key is pressed and certain conditions are met (such as distance being less than 5 and `npc.talkedTo` being falsy), I want to trigger a dialogue and set the value of an element with ID `xb1TalkedTo` to `true`. However, the value of `xb1TalkedTo` doesn't seem to be updating as expected.

Here's a simplified version of the code:

```
function handleInterest(event, npc) {
    if (event.key == 'f' && distance < 5 && !npc.talkedTo) {
        triggerDiablogue(currentDialogue);
        let xb1TalkedTo = document.querySelector('#xb1TalkedTo');
        xb1TalkedTo.value = true;
    }
   }
```

Comment: What is `xb1TalkedTo`? If it's a checkbox, use `xb1TalkedTo.checked = true`.

Comment: It's related to this HTML `<input id="xb1TalkedTo" type="hidden" value="false">`

Comment: Please add that to the question and explain why *you* think it doesn't work. I can't seem to reproduce the problem using your code.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your code is working,  because the `value` property of an element is typically used for getting or setting the value of an input element, such as an input field or a select dropdown. It might not work as expected when trying to set a boolean value directly to an element's `value` property. Instead, you can consider setting the value of an element using the `textContent` or `innerText`

```
    if (event.key == 'f' && distance < 5 && !npc.talkedTo) {
        triggerDiablogue(currentDialogue);
        let xb1TalkedTo = document.querySelector('#xb1TalkedTo');
        xb1TalkedTo.textContent = 'true';
        // Alternatively, you can use xb1TalkedTo.innerText = 'true';
    }
}
```